# IIS does not open XLS

Tags: excel, iis, model-view-controller, office-interop

I am trying to open and update an xls file on IIS server and send it to user as download. Following code is working fine under development IIS express environment. But when i deploy it on IIS server, server seems hanging on Workbooks.open function.

```
// Copy template to the given file
            System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\App_Data\\template.xls", file, true);

            // Get current project id
            int activeProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["activeProjectID"]);

            // Open workbook
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
            mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            //Get all the sheets in the workbook
            mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
```

Answer (score 1):

Server side automation using Office Interop libraries is not a supported scenario and is asking for troubles. It causes a lot of problems because:

1. Needs a user Identity
2. They interact with the desktop
3. They don't have    reentrancy and     scalability

**"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: Thanks Oscar, What are other alternatives then? I need to create an excel file with macro from database.

Comment: @Tom Use Office 2003 XML format, or Open XML, or third party libraries like Aspose Cells if you absolutely need to use the old xls binary format  https://www.aspose.com/products/cells/net